# Library with fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d?

Tags: linux, fftw

I have an error when loading a third party .so file:

```
undefined symbol: fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d
```

I have libfftw3.so installed (Ubuntu fftw3 package), but it does not define `fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d` symbol. Instead of this it has:

```
 nm -D /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so | grep fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d
000bffa0 T dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d_
000c12b0 T dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d__
000c2aa0 T fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d
```

(prefix `fftw_` instead of  `fftwf_`), according to doc it should be `fftw_` http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real_002ddata-DFTs.html, but where I can find the library which defines `fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link with the single precision (`float`) version of the FFTW library `libfftw3f.so`, not `libfftw3.so`, which is for double precision.